# Alternative to HTTP to avoid corruption when downloading

Tags: downloads, data-corruption

I have a 76GB file I want to download from my web server, but am affraid it may become corrupt when downloading via HTTP. Are there any options to download files that will check for corruption?

Comment: How about using `uGet` or `KGet`, I mean, download managers wont become handy at this point?

Comment: Adding on to the answers, if you think the file may become corrupted while transferring,and that you then have to transfer the whole file again, you could split it into multiple files on the server (using a file-splitting tool), and then download those parts individually. This way, if _one_ of the pieces is corrupted (check with hash), you only have to redownload that piece if it gets corrupted, instead of the whole file. (This is basically how bittorrent works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't mention any, I expect you don't have any restrictions regarding ports or programs on both sites.

I would download it via http with a client that can resume (e.g. `wget -c`). Then check the `md5sum`. If there is anything wrong with it, which I don't expect, I would then use rsync over ssh, which should transfer (only) the rest. Alternatively you could replace the first http transfer with the rsync, but IMO http is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

BitTorrent is also a possibility, as it ensures that each piece of the file(s) matches the original signatures.

Will also reduce server loading if many people need the file.

Answer (score 1):

zsync basically does what Jakob Lenfers suggests in his answer, but BitTorrent has proven to be the better alternative where it is available and the network connection can at least transfer some bits correctly it will get the job done for you with the least hassle for a client/receiving device. A more consumer-friendly version would be [Syncthing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncthing).